# How do I return a date in json from django

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I want to return a date in json from this django view.

```
from .models import my_orders
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import connection
import json

def test_date(request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT my_date, sum(amount) as myvalue FROM my_orders ORDER BY order_typ, my_date")
    testing = cursor.fetchall()

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(testing), content_type='application/json;charset=utf8')
```

The sql query gets me the correct result when I run it directly on the database (sqlite) but this is the result I get in json

```
[[null, 8802493.240000026], [null, 8871114.860000044], [null, 8792144.990000047], [null, 8864875.95000004]]
```

How do I get the dates in the json results instead of null?

Comment: JSON has no concept of dates. Do you want a float of the unix time, or a string of the datetime instead? `null` only appears if there is a Python `None` object, so the `null`s aren't dates.

Comment: I will like a string of the datetime